# How to insert a column in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api-php-client

I want to add new data to the start (beginning) of the sheet. So I have to add a new column A1 to the sheet. But I can't find any API example with PHP.

Now I am appending the data with this:

```
$body   = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values' => $values]);
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($new_sheet_id, 'A1:E1', $body, $options); // appent the data to the spreadsheet
```

Thanks.

UPD:
here is what I have found

```
/* insert columns */
$requests = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request(array(
    'insertDimension' => array(
        'range' => array(
            'sheetId' => 0,
            'dimension' => "COLUMNS",
            'startIndex' => 0,
            'endIndex' => 5
        )
    )
));
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));
$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($new_sheet_id, $batchUpdateRequest);
/* insert columns */
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is not possible with the Spreadsheet API. I've been studying the possibility and so far I can't see how to do that. There is an alternate solution but requires you to use the [Google Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api). Please feel free to implement if the solution is suitable. Follow these steps:

1. Create a new spreadsheet and name it whatever you want.
2. Fill out the spreadsheet so it looks the same as the image below
   [image]
3. Open the script editor by going to "Tools > Script Editor"
4. Name the project anything you want as you see in the image below
   [image]
5. Delete everyting you have inside "Code.gs" and paste the following:

   ```
   function insertColumn(vals) {

       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

       // This inserts a column in the first column position
       sheet.insertColumnBefore(1);  

       //This set the values in the cells of the first column inserted
       var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A5");
       range.setValues(vals);

   }
   ```
6. Now, go to the API manager, select your project and enable the API, like in the image below
   [image]
7. Go to your project settings and copy the **Project Number**, as in the image below
   [image]
8. Return to the script editor explained on step 3 and shown on step 4. Click on "Resources > Cloud Platform Project"
9. Paste the project number in the field that reads "Enter Project Number here" and then click on "Set Project". See image below.
   [image]
10. You will get a confirmation window. Confirm the change and wait for it to finish.
11. Inside the project editor, go to "Publish > Deploy as API Executable". Type a version and click on "Deploy". See image below
    [image]
12. It will show you a couple more of info messages and then you should see this:
    [image]
13. Please copy the **Current API ID** and then make sure to save the project changes.
14. Create a new PHP file and paste the following:

    ```
    <?php session_start(); 

    //INCLUDE PHP CLIENT LIBRARY
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    //scope required to modify the spreadsheet
    $scopes = array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets");

    // Create client object
    $client = new Google_Client(); 
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php');
    $client->setAuthConfig("client_secret.json");
    $client->setScopes($scopes);

    if( isset($_SESSION["access_token"]) && ($_SESSION["access_token"]) ) {

        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]);    
        $service = new Google_Service_Script($client);

        //Here goes the script Id you copied on step 13
        $scriptId = 'XXX-OROcbUXO78URUxxxLYqFdOk6teXXX';

        $values = array( 
            array("Email"),
            array("jonsnow@email.com"),
            array("aryastark@email.com"),
            array("sansastark@email.com"),
            array("cerseilanister@email.com")
        );

        $params = array($values);

        // Create an execution request object.
        $request = new Google_Service_Script_ExecutionRequest();
        $request->setFunction('insertColumn');
        $request->setParameters($params);
        $request->setDevMode(true); //required to work with parameters

        try {
        // Make the API request.
            $response = $service->scripts->run($scriptId, $request);

            if ($response->getError()) {
            // The API executed, but the script returned an error.

            // Extract the first (and only) set of error details. 
            // The values of this object are the script's 'errorMessage'
            // and 'errorType', and an array of stack trace elements.
            $error = $response->getError()['details'][0];
            printf("Script error message: %s\n", $error['errorMessage']);

                if (array_key_exists('scriptStackTraceElements', $error)) {
                    // There may not be a stacktrace if the script didn't start executing.
                    print "Script error stacktrace:\n";
                    foreach($error['scriptStackTraceElements'] as $trace) {
                        printf("\t%s: %d\n", $trace['function'], $trace['lineNumber']);
                    }
                }

            } else {
            // The structure of the result will depend upon what the Apps Script
            // function returns.
            $resp = $response->getResponse();    
            var_dump($resp);          

            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
            echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }    

    } else {

        if( !isset($_GET["code"]) ){

            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        } else {

            $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

            $redirect_uri = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/index.php';
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        }

    }

    ?>
    ```
15. Run the PHP script and then look at the result in your Spreadhsheet. You should see as below.
    [image]

As you can see, a column was inserted at the beginning and the values were filled out too. I hope this is helpful somehow to you or someone else.